# LazyLoading Multiple JS Files

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

I lazyload multiple script files. I want to call ***allJsLoaded()*** method when all files are loaded in order. Since the script files load synchronously, is it enough to listen to onload event of last script tag? Or is there any better approach to achieve the same?

```
//Below are the script tags I create dynamically and add it to headtag
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="file3.js" onload="allJsLoaded()"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use defer like this :
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file3.js" onload="allJsLoaded()" defer />
```

Also i'm not particularly fond of using a function on "onload".

If you want to be sure that everything is loaded, use an eventListener instead :

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(){
    //....
});
```

use this doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

While i'm on the event listener you also have this event :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //....
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: if the eventlistener is used then defer isn't really usefull. But since defer load the script once the page is entirely parsed, i'd say it's more or less the same since it should guarantee that the script isn't loaded after the ones called before no? I used it to be sure that dom content was loaded having errors being loaded too early to detect fields and it did the trick as far as i can remember.

Answer (score 0):

If the script files are loaded synchronously (meaning one after the other, in order), then listening for the onload event of the last script tag should be sufficient to ensure that all scripts have loaded before calling `allJsLoaded()`.

This approach assumes that the scripts are loaded without any errors and that they do not manipulate the loading order or execution flow. If there's a possibility that any of these conditions might not be met, you should consider `additional error handling`.

Keep in mind that in some cases, particularly if the scripts are loaded from different domains or have other complex dependencies, you might encounter issues with the `onload event due to cross-origin restrictions`. In such cases, you might need to use a more advanced script loading technique or a module loader like `RequireJS`.